# STATIC_URL not working

Tags: django

I am struggling to pull media out for my templates using the **STATIC_URL** variable. For example I have this code

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block extrahead %}
<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% firstof STATIC_URL MEDIA_URL %}django_qbe/js/excanvas.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% firstof STATIC_URL MEDIA_URL %}django_qbe/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Each time the template loads it tries to pull off the **MEDIA_URL**. If I change it to

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load static %}
{% block extrahead %}
<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% get_static_prefix %}django_qbe/js/excanvas.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% get_static_prefix %}django_qbe/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

My question is why doesn't my first version of this template work?

Comment: i'm using the zip downloaded version of this app http://versae.github.com/qbe/ from what i see he is using RequestContext.

Comment: My guess would that you don't have `"django.core.context_processors.media"` in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`

Comment: I have 'django.core.context_processors.media', in my settings.py

Answer (score 64, accepted):

There is a [static context-processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.core.context_processors.static) (Version 1.8), which isn't the same as the `media` one. You need to make sure you have `django.core.context_processors.static` in your context-processor list, so it can add `STATIC_URL` to the context.

As commented, for Django 3.0, that is now at [django.core.context_processors.static](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/api/#django-template-context-processors-static). Django sure has changed a lot since 2011...

Comment: Currently working link is https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.core.context_processors.static

Comment: In Django 3.0 should use
`django.template.context_processors.static`

Answer (score 18):

From the docs:

If {{ STATIC_URL }} isn't working in your template, you're probably not using RequestContext when rendering the template.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Comment: This solved my issue, but now I have to add the `RequestContext(request)` argument to my `render_to_response` call. Is there a more "django" way to do this?

Comment: You can just use the render() method, which auto uses the RequestContext - [link to the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render)

Answer (score 10):

Most things have already been mentioned but to compile and add a little:

1. Make sure your settings.py file correctly specifies the locations of your static files. As Steven Keith wrote, you should have something like:

   ```
   # Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
   # Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
   # in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
   # Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
   STATIC_ROOT = ''

   STATIC_URL = '/static/'

   ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'

   import os
   # Additional locations of static files
   STATICFILES_DIRS = (
       os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static'),
   )
   ```
2. Then make sure that your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS include 'django.core.context_processors.static'. If there's no entry for TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS in your settings.py, then it defaults to the below, and you're all good.

   ```
   TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
       'django.core.context_processors.debug',
       'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
       'django.core.context_processors.media',
       'django.core.context_processors.static',
       'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
       'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
   )
   ```
3. Make sure that you use RequestContext when you render your templates. `django.shortcuts.render` does this by default (see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render)), so you could just call

   ```
   from django.shortcuts import render

   def myViewFunction(request):
       return render(request, 'myTemplate.html')
   ```

   Be careful as django.shortcuts.render_to_response doesn't do this for you unless you add an argument, so you'd have to write something like

   ```
   from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

   def myViewFunction(request):
       return render_to_response('myTemplate.html', myContext, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
   ```

Answer (score 9):

For me, the answer was simply to stop using STATIC_URL, and instead use the following:

I changed mine from

```
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/survey.less" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

to:

```
<link href="{% static "css/style.less" %}" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/less"/>
```

And now it works fine.  Much simpler, and I suspect this is also the slightly "more correct" way to use static now (as of Django 1.4) anyways.  Please see the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#template-tags) for more info on the specifics.

Dont forget to add `{% load static from staticfiles %}` at the top of your templates that use it too.

Comment: This definitely the way to go with a newer Django version (v1.6=<)

Answer (score 4):

As I've been accused of not answering the question, let me clarify me thought process:

```
My question is why doesn't my first version of this template work?

STATIC_URL is returning a False value
```

To determine why, here is the steps I would use:

- Try printing it in your templates body - {{ STATIC_URL }}.
- Check settings.py to ensure the value is set - STATIC_URL = '/static/'

Check whether you have the STATIC files set up properly in runserver:

```
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/staticfiles/
```

For reference I use:

```
# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ''

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

or an Apache alias:

```
Alias /static /Users/stevenkeith/foo/bar/static

<Directory /Users/stevenkeith/foo/bar/static>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

or whatever method you want, nginx, etc

Comment: If you don't have an answer, why not to use comments?

Comment: It is an answer. It's explaining how he/she should go about debugging the problem.

Comment: @Steven Keith Have you read the question? It is 'why?'. Have you answered it? No. Comments are for comments (clarifying questions, etc.), answers are for answers, I don't understand why use one instead of another.

Comment: I tried to print the {{ STATIC_URL }} and it came back blank. I have made sure STATIC_URL = '/static/' is there and staticfiles works because I can access my files using {% get_static_prefix %}. I'm using the local development server.

Comment: It shouldn't be blank. To ensure you can actually serve the static media I'd INITIALLY hardcode the value in the template: /static/django_qbe/js/excanvas.js

Comment: Assuming that works, then focus on why you aren't getting a value for the STATIC_URL. As mentioned, ensure the template is rendered with RequestContext

Answer (score 4):

Here is a tutorial to implement load the static image

tree

[image: tree]

setting.py

[image: setting.py]

base.html

[image: base.html]

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was pointing the STATIC_ROOT and the STATIC_URL to the same static directory

**my basic file structure**

```
core/static/(
...
img/logos/green.jpg
js
css
...
)
```

...

```
STATIC_ROOT='/core/static/'
STATIC_URL='/core/static/'
```

and so in my html template I did

```
{% load static %}

<img src="{% static 'img/logos/green.jpg' %} />"
...
```

It worked!