# STATIC_URL in django cms placeholder

Tags: django, django-cms

I have a placeholder in my template:

`{% placeholder slider_content %}`

Is it possible to access `{{ STATIC_URL }}` when editing placeholder content in admin like this:

`<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/images/slides/01.png" alt="" /></div>`

Comment: @SamiN yes, and it doesn`t work. I want to know is it possible somehow? Maybe there is another way...pass variable or something.

Comment: Have a link at the following answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261823/static-url-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the plugin you are using. The text plugin won't render the contents of the WYSIWYG as a template, it will just render them as HTML so any tags you include (like `{{ STATIC_URL }}` in your example) will just be rendered as text.

When using the `placeholder` template tag (which is actually an instance of a `django-classy-tags` template tag), the context that the tag gets passed depends on the type of context used by the view. This should be a `RequestContext` when displaying a CMS page so you should have access to all your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` (such as `STATIC_URL`). So similarly, when the plugin renders its template, it should have access to that context, and any variables that go with it.