# Jinja2 templating not working in in Django 1.9

Tags: python, django, templates, jinja2

Per the instructions on the [Django 1.9 tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2) I've added another file in the project root with the Environment settings -

```
from __future__ import absolute_import  # Python 2 only

from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from jinja2 import Environment


def environment(**options):
    env = Environment(**options)
    env.globals.update({
        'static': staticfiles_storage.url,
        'url': reverse,
    })
    return env`
```

(Granted to load the proper `jinja2` I had to rename the file something differently, in this case `jinja2env.py` in project root)

And I updated `settings.py` with the new templating backend:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates').replace('\\','/')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
{
    'BACKEND': "django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2",
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'campaigns/templates').replace('\\','/')],
    "APP_DIRS": True,
    "OPTIONS": {
        'environment': 'jinja2env.Environment',
    }
},
```

In the view I'm working on I use the `using` parameter to specify the `jinja2` templating engine:

```
return render(request, 'jinja2/index.html', context={'projects': projects, 'counter': 0}, status=200, using='jinja2')
```

Yet when the template goes to render I have following error: `'static' is undefined`. Clearly my setup is wrong or I am not doing something correct. The template starts as such:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ static('stylesheets/main.css') }}">
```

What am I doing wrong? I don't use `{% load static %}` since it isn't a Django template ... so I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're loading the wrong environment. In your code `jinja2env.Environment` actually refers to default Environment from `jinja2.Environment`.

```
"OPTIONS": {
    'environment': 'jinja2env.Environment',
}
```

should be changed to

```
"OPTIONS": {
    'environment': 'jinja2env.environment',
}
```

Notice the lowercase `environment`, which is the environment you defined inside `jinja2env.py`.

Comment: Wow. Love those capitalization errors. (Ha - not really. Poor readership on my part!) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your settings and the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261823/static-url-not-working), it appears you should try adding the `static` context processor.